# GridBagLayout is not working when I add it to the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm having some issues with my GridBagLayout. I have created a JPanel (in this case it's called mainPanel), whose layout has been set to GridBagLayout. I have specified the constraints for each JButton, and added the constraints to each button. Now, when I run my code, the buttons are always next to each other, irrespective of the gridx/gridy value that I indicate in the constraints. Furthermore, the buttons are always at the center of the JFrame, when I would like one button to appear at the top right, top left, and south.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    myJFrame test = new myJFrame();
    }
}

class myJFrame extends JFrame {
   public myJFrame () {
      setSize(500,500);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      mainPanel myPanel = new mainPanel();
      add(myPanel);

     setVisible(true);
 }
}

class mainPanel extends JPanel {
    public mainPanel(){
       setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
       GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.anchor =      GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        c.gridx =       1000;
        c.gridy=        1;
        add(new JButton("1"),c);

        c.anchor =      GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        c.gridx =       100;
        c.gridy=        1;
        add(new JButton("2"),c);

        c.anchor =      GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        c.gridx =       200;
        c.gridy=        1;
        add(new JButton("3"),c);
   }
}
```

[This is what i get when i run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC06Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I run my code, the buttons are always next to each other, irrespective of the gridx/gridy value that I indicate in the constraints.

Correct, you can't just specify random cells. A component must be located in each cell.

> Furthermore, the buttons are always at the center of the JFrame,

Yes, this is the default behaviour if you don't specify a weightx/weighty constraint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on constraints and working examples.

Why are you picking random x locations like 100, 200, 1000? Maybe a horizontal `BoxLayout` would be a better layout manager. You can add the components and then add space between them:

```
panel.add( button1 );
panel.add( Box.createHorizonalStrut(100);
panel.add( button2 );
panel.add( Box.createHorizonalStrut(200);
```

Or maybe use a FlowLayout and specify the "gap" between each component.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed you are correct, it was an issue with the weights- once i modified this I was able to get the behavior I was expecting. As for the x locations, it was just to show that irrespective of the size of the location in the x coordinate, the items were appearing next to each other. Thanks!

Comment: @newbieJavaDev, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.